# How To Pass a PHP Variable To Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$your_name=$_POST['name'];
?>
<script language="javascript">
function fash(at1,at2)
{
    alert(at1+at2);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $your_name;
echo '<script language="javascript">fash("the key is: "+'<?php echo $your_name; ?>');</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

> the key is : undefined

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be the right code, it has syntax errors (e.g. you have a `<?php` block inside another `<?php` block). Probably the line that outputs a script tag is supposed to look like this:

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">fash(\"the key is: $your_name\");</script>";
```

Or like this:

```
?>
<script language="javascript">fash("the key is: <?php echo $your_name; ?>");</script>
<?php
```

That will get it to output "the key is: testnameundefined" (if `$your_name` is `testname`). The undefined comes from you defining `fash` to take two arguments and concatenate them, but you only passing one; `at2` is undefined

Comment: This will break if $your_name contains a doublequote. Best to do something like 'var somevar = <?php echo json_encode($your_name) ?>;` beforehand and use somevar instead.

Comment: @Marc Good point; some sort of sanitation is always a good idea, just outputting form variables directly won't end well

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see what´s going on with all the editing, but it seems you are using `<?php  ?>` tags when you are already inside `php` tags.

Just echoing and removing the inner `<?php  ?>` should solve part of your problem, although it seems that your javascript function wants 2 paramenters as well instead of one (the text given).

Answer (score 1):

You're passing only *one* parameter into your function:

```
fash("the key is: "+'php_value');
```

`"the key is: "` and your php string are concatenated before the function is called.

Try

```
fash("the key is: ", 'php_value');
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The function `fash` takes two parameters. You are only passing one.

Use:

```
fash("the key is: ", "$your_name");
```

This will correctly display the alert after it concatenates these two strings. You do not need the PHP tags here because you are already in a PHP code block.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your definition of `fash`, you take two parameters and concatenate them there, but in your echoed script, you concatenate them there and so only pass one parameter. So `at2` is passed as undefined. Clearly your name is also blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script language="javascript">fash("the key is: "+'<?php echo $your_name; ?>');</script>';
```

It looks like you're echo'ing php code inside a php echo. Try changing it to:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">fash("the key is: "+'$your_name;');</script>';
```

Not sure if that solves the entire problem but I'm pretty sure you can't echo a new echo inside an echo.