# How to pass php variable's value to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php variable:

```
$name_of_current_page
```

which I have available in my view, and I want to make the value available to jquery. Is the best way to do it like the following?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var current page = "<?php echo $name_of_current_page; ?>" ;

});
```

Comment: Yes. At least the simplest.  You could over complicate this is you wanted to by doing an AJAX request to the server for the data and then loading your variable that way.

Comment: perhaps not the best but work fine :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Pass a PHP Variable To Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742515/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It really depends if you are using some sort of a template engine.

1. If you're using plain PHP, the only option for you is to `echo` the variable:

   ```
   var current page = "<?php echo $your_var; ?>";
   ```
2. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) engine:

   ```
   var current page = "{{ your_var }}";
   ```
3. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [RainTPL](http://www.raintpl.com/) engines:

   ```
   var current page = "{$your_var}";
   ```

As you can see, there are other ways. All of them work fine. It really depends on how you'd like to write and organize your code. I personally use Twig and find it really easy,fast and straightforward.

Also, as others have pointed out, you can do AJAX calls to the server and fetch the variables like that. I find that method time-consuming, inefficient and insecure. If you choose this method, you will be posting requests to a script. Everybody will be able to do post/get requests to that script which opens your doors to some bots and DoS/DDoS attacks.

Comment: Saying using AJAX opens your doors to bots and DoS is akin to saying putting anything on the web opens the doors. While factually, this is true, but there are lots of reasons to use AJAX to pull data into javascript. Every major site, IDK like Google, Facebook, et al. does this.

Putting a simple index.php out there with <?php echo "Hello World"; ?> opens him up to DoS attacks.  If his webservice is designed properly, then he need not worry (as much) about someone getting a hold of his data.

Comment: @MichaelRice don't get me wrong - using AJAX is great. But it rises some issues. So it should be used wisely. And comparing Google,Facebook,etc with probably a small-to-medium site is wrong. Google can afford having those services public, because they have unlimited system resources and can handle bots/DoS/DDoS at a glance, whereas small-to-medium sites will simply go offline.

Answer (score 6):

var **current page** = "" ;

I don't think you can have spaces in a variable. (i could be wrong).

Anyway to simplify your code, I've just done re-done it slightly.

```
$name_of_current_page = "HomePage";
```

And for the Javascript;

```
var currentPage = "<?= $name_of_current_page; ?>";
```

That should be it.

Comment: You can have whitespaces in your variables. Exept for the php tags this is the right way. You could better not use short tags with php. Instead of "<?=" use "<?php" [PHP 6 is officially deprecating short tags] If I am right about this

Comment: @RensTillmann Some of what I've found indicates that it's the short php tags (`<?` and `?>`) that are being removed, while short _echo_ tags (`<?=` and `?>`) are staying in.  Do you have a link to an official resource?

Comment: Right, didn't read the source well enough: http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html - (Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is ALWAYS available)

Comment: @RensTillmann Thanks for clarifying that for me. I didn't know you could have spaces in Javascript a var. :P

Answer (score 0):

`document.title` should give you what you need.. things like this either query the DOM or Ajax imho.

I find it best to separate layers, and not mix presentation and controller with peppered html/php code.

Comment: `$name_of_current_page` don't have to means `document.title`.

Comment: @furas what else might it mean?

Comment: `<h1>name_of_current_page</h1>` or can be used in many other tags as `title="..."` or `alt=".."` for some SEO reasons ;)

Comment: Thanks, but in my case its not the page title

Answer (score 0):

First at all, that you ask, is a normal way on fill client side code, but this one will be load at the page load, if you want to run it on live once the page is loaded, you must use ajax, cause is the way on how you will comunicate with the server side scripts, is no possible jquery or javascript load the php vars on live once the page have been loaded